# Apache .htaccess <FilesMatch> // Setting as forbidden subfolder files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm going mad over Apache .htaccess

I'm trying to setting as protected my subfolders using relative address, but it seems impossible.

The path of Apache folder is structured like this:

```
/var/www/apachedir
```

now I want to protect

```
/var/www/apachedir/subfolder/*
```

What I tryied is putting in `/var/www/apachedir/` an `.htaccess` file like this

```
<FilesMatch "subfolder\/.*">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

but it seems not woking good.

I don't want to use `ModRewrite` and I want to make this `.htaccess` reusable.

So, listen, if I put the site over an other server that has a direcory structure like `/var/www/zzz` it has to protect files in `/var/www/zzz/subfolder/*`.

**Also the file `.htaccess` has to stay in the root folder `/var/www/apachedir`.**

There's a way to do it?

Edit:
I don't want to use `ModRewrite` but also I don't want to use `Redirectmatch`.

I want to know if there's a way to set it up with `FilesMatch` without `ModRewrite` or `Redirectmatch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to use `ModRewrite`.

You can use `RedirectMatch` to block access to a known path:

```
Redirectmatch 403 ^/subfolder/
```

Comment: It works surely. But I don't want to use `ModRewrite` and also `Redirectmatch` to obtain the forbidden error (403) for the subfolder. I want to know if there's a way to set it up in a relative way with `FilesMatch`. Tnx tha same

Comment: It is definitely not mod_rewrite and it is much simpler than any other alternative

Comment: It is definitely not mod_rewrite and it is much simpler than any other alternative. I know. So none gives me other messages. I put you question like helpful 

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know if there's a way to set it up with `FilesMatch`

No, because the `FilesMatch` (and the non-regex `Files`) directive(s) literally match against *files* only, not directories. eg. `<Files "*.jpg">` matches all `.jpg` files in *any* subdirectory.

There are various methods to block access to that subdirectory...

#### Use a `<Directory>` section in the server config

If you have access to the server (virtual host) config then you can use the `<Directory>` (and `<DirectoryMatch>`) directive(s) to target specific directories. But this is not permitted in `.htaccess`. For example:

```
<Directory "/var/www/apachedir/subfolder">
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

#### Create an additional `.htaccess` file in that subdirectory

The equivalent *userland* `.htaccess` way of doing this is to create an additional `.htaccess` file in that subdirectory (ie. at `/subfolder/.htaccess`) with a single `Require all denied` directive. The `.htaccess` file itself is equivalent to the `<Directory>` directive in the server config.

*Aside:* `Order`, `Deny` and `Allow` are Apache 2.2 directives and formerly deprecated on Apache 2.4 (which you are far more likely to be using). You should be using the equivalent `Require` (mod_authz_core) directives instead, as used above.

#### Use `Redirect 403` (mod_alias) - not a "redirect"

> I don't want to use ModRewrite but also I don't want to use Redirectmatch

`RedirectMatch` (and `Redirect`) are part of mod_alias - this is a *base* module and compiled into Apache by default (unlike mod_rewrite), so using the prefix-matching `Redirect` directive (no need for the regex variant `RedirectMatch`) is a reasonable solution as [@anubhava suggests in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73198812/369434), depending on the scenario and existing directives. For example:

```
Redirect 403 /subfolder/
```

Despite the use of the `Redirect` directive, this is *not* an external (HTTP) redirect. The 403 response is served via an internal subrequest.

#### Set an environment variable and check with mod_authz_....

Alternatively, you can set an environment variable when the `/subfolder` is requested (using `SetEnvIf`) and check for this using the `Require` directive. This allows you to keep the condition separate from the directives that actually permit access. For example (using Apache 2.4 mod_authz_core):

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/subfolder/" BLOCK_ACCESS
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require not env BLOCK_ACCESS
</RequireAll>
```

NB: If you are doing any URL-rewriting with mod_rewrite then you might need to check for `REDIRECT_BLOCK_ACCESS` instead in the above `Require` directive.

#### `<If>` expression (Apache 2.4)

On Apache 2.4 you can also use an `<If>` expression to target that specific subfolder with a containing mod_authz_core directive. For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/subfolder/#">
    Require all denied
</If>
```

Although, strictly speaking, these methods target the URL-path, not the file-path.

Comment: ++ve for very detailed and nice answer. just want to be on same page here, so these rules wouldn't work below 2.4 version of apache?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 `<If>` is Apache 2.4 only (no equivalent in earlier versions). The authorization directives `<RequireAll>` (and `Require all granted` / `Require not env ...`) are Apache 2.4. On Apache 2.2 (and earlier) you can use the `Order`, `Allow` and `Deny` directives instead. The other directives (`Redirect` and `SetEnvIf`) are not version dependent.

Comment: If you specifically _need_ a portable "any version" code block when using the "authorization" directives then you can check for installed modules (using `<IfModule>` wrappers). However, you should never mix authorization directives from both modules. So even on Apache 2.4 it might not be correct to use `Require` (mod_authz_core) directives when the deprecated `Order`, `Deny` and `Allow` (mod_access_compat) directives are still in use. @RavinderSingh13

Comment: Thanks a TON for nicely explained statements above @MrWhite

Comment: So I can't do what I wanted to do. Tnk a ton ton ton the same @MrWhite 4 the good explaination of the answer at this question and RavinderSingh13 for the comment about apache 2.4.